# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"EditProfileScreen"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im getting the following issue:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"EditProfileScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'EditProfileScreen'?
```

My code:

settingsNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import SettingsScreen from "../screens/settingsScreen";
import EditProfileScreen from "../screens/editProfileScreen"

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

const SettingsNavigator = () => (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
)

export default SettingsNavigator
```

settingScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper'

import Screen from '../Components/Screen'

function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EditProfileScreen")}>
                <Card style={styles.list} >
                    <Text>Edit Profile</Text>
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Screen>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
})

export default SettingsScreen
```

editProfileScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import Screen from '../Components/Screen'

function EditProfileScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>Edit Profile Screen</Text>
        </Screen>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
})

export default EditProfileScreen
```

I have tried wrapping my `settingNavigation` in a `NavigationContainer`, but thats not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return JSX in settingsNavigator.js file

```
const SettingsNavigator = () => (
     return (
       <SettingsStack.Navigator>
           <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
           <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
       </SettingsStack.Navigator>
     );
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const SettingsNavigator = () => {
   return <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
}
```

Add return this type